# Drag & Drop OnTouch irregular shaped images

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I am working on a simple app, which will allow moving one ImageView & dropping it on another ImageView. I am having problems with how onTouch works. It seems that it always takes rectangular input.

Let's say I have a shape like that:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfPdB.png)

All small dots represent places which will trigger onTouch. But only green ones should... So in other words, I do not want Drag to be triggered when I am touching transparent part of the image.

Is this possible?

BR,
Kuba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will stumble upon this question, here is an answer: You must extend the DragShadowBuilder class to achieve that. More details in below question:

[Set custom anchor when dragging a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458307/set-custom-anchor-when-dragging-a-view)