# Android - Drag and Drop view - center view after Drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm using in my app D&D system. When user do LongClick() on the view I call

```
 view.startDrag()
```

But the view is automatically centered in the middle of the touch. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Solution for my problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458307/set-custom-anchor-when-dragging-a-view

Answer (score 0):

To set a `View` of your choice as drag shadow, first inflate the `View`.

```
View myShadowView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.shadow_layout, null);
```

Then the drag could be started like this:

```
View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(myShadowView);
view.startDrag(data, myShadowBuilder, position, 0);
```

You can use a custom `View.DragShadowBuilder` in order to get a touch point which is not centered. There are three methods to override, `onProvideShadowMetrics()` lets you choose the touch point for the shadow.

For further information, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html)